# Vote early, vote often

Tags: discussion

Just echoing an important Stack Exchange sentiment from the [Vote early, vote often blog post:](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)

> Putting voting front and center is very much intentional; it is how good content is voted to the top wrong or incorrect content is voted
>   to the bottom users who consistently provide useful content accrue
>   reputation and are granted more privileges on the site It’s only
>   through voting that a class of editors, closers, and moderators can
>   emerge to help run and govern the site. Voting is how site leadership
>   forms. That’s why the reputation leagues show a breakdown of
>   reputation spectrums.

Voting (up and down) starts the sorting process of questions and answers and shapes the site. It gives people more privileges to properly tend to the site. In a nutshell voting is what makes Stack Exchange sites work.

So go ahead and vote.

Answer (score 8):

*Just to add a point which rarely comes up —*

There is no shortage of information on the Internet. What a Stack Exchange site brings to the table is the ability for a community of engaged users to broadly *vet* and edit and correct just about *everything* you see here. But you have to use those tools.

I'm sure folks have seen some terrible advice on various sites they frequent, and plenty of outdated, blatantly wrong information online. But with a vigilant, engaged community, using those wiki-style editing tools, and sorting the best, most complete information to the top helps assure everything you post here stays relevant — and creates a ***useful*** collection of knowledge for the folks who come after.